# Is there a way to track an extension's resource usage?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've noticed through GitHub and Google search that a lot of people have similar issues as mine: vscode hangs and apart from the text editor, nothing works. Sometimes everything but debugging works.

As usual, disabling all extensions make it work perfectly. Checking developer tools, I can notice `[Extension Host]` working like crazy.

My question is: is there a way to check each extension's usage of process, disk, etc? Something similar to Google Chrome's Task Manager.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of VSCode 1.23 (April 2018), [there is now a Process Explorer built-in](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_see-the-running-visual-studio-code-processes). It can be opened with the `Developer: Open Process Explorer` command:

[image]